# Where can i find MyDbAdapter.java class for Android?

Tags: android, sql

i need to know where i can find that class, the original website

why? because i have to put it on the bibliography of my work

thanks

Comment: Need more info than that. There are probably a bagillion MyDbAdapter.java files on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)?

Comment: no, MyDbAdapter.java, a very common used adapter for use sqlite local databases on android apps